# Outputting one directory below with Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, stylus

My folder structure looks like this:

```
-- Project
  - public
    - styles
  - node
    - gulpfile.js
    - styles
      - global.styl
```

I want to output converted `global.css` file into `/public` folder.

My code as follows:

```
gulp.task('stylus', function () {
    return gulp.src('./styles/global.styl')
      .pipe(stylus())
      .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
      .on('error', handleError)
      .pipe(gulp.dest('../public/styles'));
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

What does your script yield?

Looking at the script, it must create the output as `public/styles/styles/global.css`.

Adding the option `{ base: './styles/' }` to `gulp.src` should output the file where you expect it. Check [gulp.src API](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#optionsbase) for more.

Hope this helps

Comment: In that case shouldn't it create a folder as well? So, at least I should be able to see the resulting CSS in a wrong directory, but I get no output at all.

Comment: Oh right I see. In that case it might be one of the tools silently erroring. If the glob pattern given to gulp.src does not resolve any sources, it will successfully run without any files emitted, but your pattern seem to be correct. Maybe try a looser pattern, something like `./**/*.styl` and see if anything happens.